# Array Sort by Remainder

Tags: java, arrays, performance, sorting

A interviewer wrecked my life with this sort question today.
You have an array of a million integers and you need to sort them by remainder.
1. You don't know what integer they are going to divide by.
2. You can't use classes such as a Comparator to help.
3. Loop as little as possible.
4. Keep in mind to conserve memory.

For instance

```
int[] ints = {5434, 3454, 2, 0, 356, 896, 7324, 888, 99, 78365, 111};  
int divider = 27;
```

Would be

```
int[] int2 = {0, 2, 111, 356, 896, 5434, 7324, 78365, 99, 888, 3454};
```

The method I came up with loops = divider / 2.
It works but if the divider is 250 then it loops 125 times.

```
public void sortByMod(int[] millionInts, int divideBy) {
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    int[] b = new int[millionInts.length];
    int remainder, remainderMin = 0, remainderMax = divideBy, positionMin = 0, positionMax = millionInts.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < millionInts.length;) {
        for (int j = 0; j < millionInts.length; j++) {
            remainder = millionInts[j] % divideBy;
            if (remainder == remainderMin) {
                b[positionMin] = millionInts[j];
                positionMin++;
                i++;
            } else if (remainder == remainderMax) {
                b[positionMax] = millionInts[j];
                positionMax--;
                i++;
            }
        }
        remainderMax--;
        remainderMin++;
    }
    System.out.println("time = " + (System.nanoTime() - time));
    System.out.println("loopcount = " + remainderMin);
}
```

I wrote another method that can do it in 2 loops but its confusing to read.
It violates the memory constraint but is extremely fast.

```
public void sortByModPro(int[] millionInts, int divideBy) {
    int[] range = new int[divideBy];
    int[] remainders = new int[millionInts.length];
    int[] newArray = new int[millionInts.length];
    long times = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < millionInts.length; i++) {
        remainders[i] = millionInts[i] % divideBy;
        range[millionInts[i] % divideBy]++;
    }
    for (int i = range.length - 1, past = millionInts.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        range[i] = past - range[i];
        past = range[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < millionInts.length; i++) {
        newArray[range[remainders[i]]] = millionInts[i];
        range[remainders[i]]++;
    }
    System.out.println("time = " + (System.nanoTime() - times));
}
```

How would you do this with 1 loop?

Comment: An array in Java cannot hold a million integers. Didn't the interviewer know this?

Comment: Google for quicksort, and implement it with a small variation: instead of comparing the integers in the array directly, compare their remainder.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Of course it can. Why couldn't it?

Comment: @JBNizet `length` of an array in Java is stored in an `int`.

Comment: Yes, so? 2^31 is much much larger than 1 million. https://ideone.com/fGUU89

Comment: @JBNizet My bad. You are right. I messed up the range.

Comment: Its just an array of a integers but of course there are a lot of them.  The interviewer said he can do it with 1 loop but didn't tell me how.  I thought about it forever and I just can't grasp how to do it in 1 loop.

Answer (score 2):

**Speed > Memory**

You can loop only once by using a bunch of buckets, one for each remainder. Simply dump the numbers in the buckets based on their remainder and then merge the buckets. Of course this violates the memory constraint.

**Use your array to hold the buckets**

The problem with the buckets is that you need to at least add a reference to each item in the array. What you could do to avoid that is partition the array into buckets and maintain a reference to the start and end index of each bucket. Of course this uses some memory, but the divideBy parameter should be rather small, right?

So, here's some pseudocode:

```
// init each bucket with 0 elements
for (remainder=0; remainder<divideBy; remainder++) {
  buckets = {
    start : 0, // startIndex in the array
    end: 0, // the index after the last item actually placed in the bucket
    count: 0 // how many items should be in the bucket  
  }
}
// count how many elements fit in each bucket
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  buckets[array[i]%divideBy].count++;
}
// init the start and end points of each bucket
elementsCounted=0;
for (remainder=0; remainder<divideBy; remainder++) {
  buckets[remainder].start = elementsCounted;
  buckets[remainder].end = elementsCounted;
  elementsCounted += buckets[remainder].count;
}

// at this point each bucket starts where it should in the array, but has no elements

// loop through the array and place items in the right bucket by swapping them
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  remainder = array[i]%divideBy;
  if (i < buckets[remainder].start || i >= buckets[remainder].end) {
    // array[i] is in the wrong bucket, swap it at the end of the right bucket
    swap(array[i], array[buckets[remainder].end]);
    buckets[remainder].end++;
    i--;
  }  
}

// everything is in the right place
```

You will note that there is an i-- in the final for, so it technically could go on forever. That is not the case, i will stay in place only if the array[i] is not in the right place. Each iteration will either place an element in the correct position or advance to the next position if the element is not in the correct position. All in all, it will iterate at most 2N times.

**Total time complexity: O(3N+divideBy) = O(N + divideBy)**

**Total extra space used: divideBy*sizeof(bucket) = divideBy*12**

Comment: This looks like the second method I put together.  I mean the divider could be small but he said it could be 2000 which isn't to large for something like this.

Comment: This method looks great I'm going to try to implement it in the morning.  Thanks again I'll give you a check when i implement it.